# R dygraphs - plot certain content of columns

Tags: r, csv, xts, dygraphs

I have a csv file `"fruit.csv"` looking like that:

```
"Date","Fruit","Count"
2019-01-01,Apple,3
2019-01-01,Pear,5
2019-01-01,Banana,4
2019-02-01,Apple,4
2019-02-01,Pear,4
2019-02-01,Banana,6
...
```

I want to plot the data having the date in the x-axis and the number in the y-axis. Especially, i want the graph to only show the data of a certain fruit, e.g. only apples.
This is what I have until now, plotting all fruits at once:

```
data <- read.csv("Path/to/fruit.csv")

data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date)

time_series <- xts(data$Count, order.by = data$Date)
dygraph(time_series)
```

What do I need to add, to specify the fruit I want to plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some approaches:

First, use `dplyr` to `filter()` the data ahead of time:

```
library(dplyr)
apples <- data %>%
  filter(Fruit == "Apple")
apples_ts <- xts(apples$Count, order.by = apples$Date)
dygraph(apples_ts)
```

Second, subset the data in a more traditional way ahead of time.

```
apples <- data[which(data$Fruit == "Apples"),]
apples_ts <- xts(apples$Count, order.by = apples$Date)
dygraph(apples_ts)
```

Third, subset the data in the call to `xts`:

```
apples_ts <- xts(data[data$Fruit == "Apple",]$Count, 
                 order.by = data[data$Fruit == "Apple",]$Date)
dygraph(apples_ts)
```

Fourth, write a custom function so you don't need to repeat this code for each fruit:

```
fruit_dygraph <- function(data, fruit) {
  fruit_ts <- xts(data[data$Fruit == fruit,]$Count, 
                 order.by = data[data$Fruit == fruit,]$Date)
  dygraph(fruit_ts)
  }
fruit_dygraph(data, fruit = "Apple")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Providing plenty approaches really helps me as a beginner to understand whats happening.

Comment: However, option #3 will give me an error: `undefined columns selected`.
Is something missing there?

Comment: Option #3 was missing a critical comma in the second subset. #3 should work now.

Comment: Almost there, I just found out, you still have to add `order.by = as.Date(data[...])`